# Permission issues trying to add projecetserver scope or access _api/ProjectData/* via HTTP Requests using Bearer Token

Tags: sharepoint

- Our `server` has Single-Sign-On, when I manually login, and go to
  below URL (in chrome) I am to get Projects XML OData Feed
  `https://{server}.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects`
- I need to take this data and manually save the file to run my python
  scripts. This becomes a nightmare as I need to download all the
  relational data (resources, assignment, etc. ) to get the full scope of things
- I would like to do this via python GET requests. I have done the
  below steps, but now stuck with the following error and do not know how to overcome it:
- HTTP RESPONSE: 403
  {'odata.error': {'code': '-2147024891,
  Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Exceptions.ProjectServerUnauthorizedAccessException',
  'message': {'lang': 'en-US', 'value': 'User
   could not be authenticated
  because logon permission has not been granted'}}}

Steps I've taken to get REST API Access:

1. PWA is set to "Project Permission Mode"
2. Use the following site to create AppId: `https://{server}.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx`
3. Register the application and define the scope using the following url: `https://{server}.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`
4. The Request XML I used is the following:
   `<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true"><AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/projectserver" Right="Manage" /></AppPermissionRequests>`
   however, when I press **CREATE**, I am presented with the following landing page: `"Sorry, you don't have access"`
5. I tried scopes: `Scope="http://sharepoint/projectserver/project" Right="Read"`, same issue as above
6. Finally, I applied: `<AppPermissionRequests><AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl"/></AppPermissionRequests>` and the App was registered
7. However when it came time to accessing the URL for the project. I am presented with the HTML response I outline above. (Please note that I am getting the Bearer Token successfully, as I am able to hit the following url and get the web list: `https://{server}.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/web Response: 200`)
8. **I assume whatever permission is preventing me to register the projectserver scope is what is causing me the error. However, I have added myself to all the Permission groups, but still not able to add the projectserver scope.**
9. Are you able to highlight some steps, and possible issues I might be able to take to our sharepoint team to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following package and instructions:

- https://github.com/areed1192/ms-graph-python-client
- with youtube guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBslvqBCjAA
- and accompanying solution: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/294271/permission-issues-trying-to-add-projecetserver-scope-or-access-api-projectdata/295279?noredirect=1#comment312859_295279

  ```
    sharepoint_resource_url = 'https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com'
    credential_dir = directory to save refresh token details 

    from ms_graph.client import MicrosoftGraphClient

    graph_client = MicrosoftGraphClient(
        client_id=os.environ['client_id'],
        client_secret=os.environ['client_secret'],
        redirect_uri=os.environ['redirect_uri'],
        scope=[os.environ['sharepoint_resource_url'] + '/.default'],
        account_type=os.environ['tenent_id'],
        credentials=os.environ['credential_dir'] + '/ms_graph_state.jsonc'
    )

    graph_client.login()
    headers = dict(authorization='Bearer ' + graph_client.access_token)


    resp = request.get(os.environ['sharepoint_resource_url'] + '/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectData/Projects', headers=headers)

    print(resp.status_code)
    print(resp.content)
  ```